# Bootstrap date-picker calendar issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Bootstrap date-picker to select mm/dd/yyyy, and seeing wired behavior with calendar  [image]

some of the next month day's value is encountered in current month calendar. I have tried with css background color and z-index properties but didn't succeed.

When I inspect it in the developer tools I see two `tr` with:

```
<tr>
   <td class="day disabled">27</td>
   <td class="day disabled">28</td>
   <td class="day">29</td>
   <td class="day">30</td>
   <td class="day new">1</td>
   <td class="day new">2</td>
   <td class="day new">3</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td class="day new">4</td>
  <td class="day new">5</td>
  <td class="day new">6</td>
  <td class="day new">7</td>
  <td class="day new">8</td>
  <td class="day new">9</td>
  <td class="day new">10</td>
</tr>
```

which are causing the overlapping.

Comment: But i can't inspect element on your image.

Comment: @rails_id updated the answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the style like this:

```
.new {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```